# Unable to access modem interface from a router

Tags: router

Have question about my home network.

I buy a router with wifi for my home network. I have a modem from my ISP, but my new router have a better wifi.

I have configured like this:

```
i1 = modem        192.168.2.1
i2 = router 192.168.0.1
pc1 = My pc 192.168.0.100

pc1 ===wifi===> i2
i2 ====cable port #3==> i1
i1 ==========>internet
```

The problem is:
When my PC try to open the ISP modem web interface(192.168.2.1)

I got an

```
error connection timed out
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (chrome)
```

I can access my router web interface

```
192.168.0.1
```

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, home networking questoins are off-topic here.  You can ask your question on Superuser

Comment: Can you give us more details about your network topology, seems you are trying to log into web configuration interface from another network but im not sure.

Comment: try adding a 2nd IPV4 gateway to your network config with 192.168.2.1, and a 2nd IPV4 IP of 192.168.2.50